Find the rank of the Projection operator $P_j.$
My attempt and understanding
I know the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process. Suppose we are given linearly independent set {$ \vec{a}_1, \vec{a}_2,..., \vec{a}_n $}
$\vec{v}_1=\vec{a}_1=I \vec{a}_1=P_1\vec{a}_1\implies \vec{q}_1=\frac{P_1\vec{a}_1}{||P_1\vec{a}_1||}$
$\vec{v}_2=\vec{a}_1-(\vec{q}_1^T \vec{a}_1)\vec{q}_1=I\vec{a}_1-\vec{q}_1(\vec{q}_1^\star \vec{a}_1)=I\vec{a}_1-(\vec{q}_1\vec{q}_1^\star )\vec{a}_1(\because$ by associativity)
$=(I-\vec{q}_1\vec{q}_1^T)\vec{a}_1.$
Choose $\hat{Q_1}=[\vec{q}_1].\therefore P_2=I-\hat{Q_1}\hat{Q_1}^\star$ Then $\vec{q}_2=\frac{P_2 \vec a_2}{||P_2 \vec a_2||}$
Similarly in the $j$ th step, we get
$\vec{v_j}=\vec{a_j}-\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}(\vec{q_k }\vec{q_k}^\star) \vec{a_k}=I\vec{a_j}-[\vec{q_1 }\vec{q_2} ... \vec{q_{j-1}}][\vec{q_1} \vec{q_2} ... \vec{q_{j-1}}]^\star \vec{a_j}$
$=I \vec{a_j}- \hat{Q_{j-1}}\hat{Q_{j-1}}^\star \vec{a_j}$
$P_j=I-\hat{Q_{j-1}}\hat{Q_{j-1}}^\star$
$P_j \vec{a_j}=\frac{P_j \vec{a_j}}{||P_j\vec{a_j}||}$
We know that $P_j \vec{a_j}$ is the perpendicular to the space $\text{span} ${ $\vec{q_1},...,\vec{q_{j-1}}$}

Doubt: What do you mean by $P_j$ projects orthogonally onto the space
orthogonal to $\text{span} ${ $\vec{q_1},...,\vec{q_{j-1}}$}?

For finding the rank of $P_j$. We use Rank nullity theorem. Suppose $\vec{a_j}\in \mathbb {C}^m.$
Then $P_j\in \mathbb C^{m,m}.$
$\text{rank}(P_j)+\text{Nullity}(P_j)=m$
$\text{rank}(P_j)=m-(j-1) (\because N(P_j)=\text{span} ${ $\vec{q_1},...,\vec{q_{j-1}}$})
Please address my doubt. Is my proof correct?

I don't understand your "doubt". What part of the statement do you not understand? Do you understand what it means to "project orthogonally"? Do you understand what it means for two spaces to be perpendicular? Do you actually understand the statement but not understand why the statement is true?

But yes, your proof is correct

Why do you care about $P_j$ and its rank ? You should care about the projection $Q_j$ onto  the span of $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{j-1}.$ Then you consider $a_j-Q_ja_j$ which is orthogonal to $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_{j-1}.$ Clearly $P_j=I-Q_j.$

okay. Thank you all. @RyszardSzwarc $Q_j=\hat{Q_{j-1}}\hat{Q_{j-1}}^\star$. Right?

Perhaps it is true. I am a little bit lost in your notation.

I got this notation from this lecture note https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/75282/18-335j-fall-2006/contents/lecture-notes/lec5.pdf
